# Looking for a story about a man who can't tell if he's in a futuristic paradise or being punished

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a story about a man who is dreaming of being in a very luxurious, wonderful paradise.  When he wakes up her finds he's actually living on an isolated, frozen planet, and the paradise doesn't exist.

However, the story goes on to suggest that perhaps he really is in paradise, but in order to make his enjoyment of it sustainable over the long term, he is occasionally made to forget where he is, and is subjected to a period of time living on the isolated planet; that reminder allows him him value his true existence more.

I'd guess it's from the 80s or earlier, and isn't longer than 10 or 20 pages.

Comment: A man who doesn't know if he's in paradise or being punished. Sounds like marriage.

Comment: Interestingly a very polar opposite of Niven & Pournelle's [Inferno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_%28Niven_and_Pournelle_novel%29) -- the hero awakens in Hell, and wonders if he's actually in a horrific futuristic theme park or something similar..

Comment: @Omegacron from the accepted answer you may have been right! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

George Henry Smith ['In the Imagicon'](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?71134) published in *Galaxy Magazine* in 1966, and republished in *Nebula Award Stories 2*.

There is an [audio production on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WPLM6NbjDg):

> An audio book from the Mindweb series
> originally broadcast during the 1970's.
>
> Written by George Henry Smith.
>
> Isolated on a cold and desolate colony world and nagged by a shrewish wife, a husband's only escape is through a virtual reality machine.

Comment: The story really hasn't aged well, especially in its attitude toward women. I find a lot to agree with in [this blog post](http://actsofminortreason.blogspot.com/2014/09/tailings-of-golden-age-2-in-imagicon.html)